# Order data by two columns

Tags: sql

How can I order a set of data, by two seperate columns?

One of the two columns is not always 0, I need it ordered by the largest of either column.

Currently getting this set of data from

```
order by Value1 desc, Value2 desc;

Name       |  Value1     |  Value 2
----------------------------------------
  A        |    17       |    0
  B        |    11       |    0
  C        |    0        |    57
  D        |    0        |    15
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
    Name       |  Value1     |  Value 2
    ----------------------------------------
      C        |    0        |    57
      A        |    17       |    0
      D        |    0        |    15
      B        |    11       |    0
```

Comment: Is one of the two columns always 0; you could order by the sum?

Comment: Not always 0, edited for clarity.

Comment: Why should it be like that? What's the logic behind the sort?

Comment: Value1 and Value2 both are counts of an occurrence of separate events. I want to see the highest ranked 'Name', regardless whether its ranked by Value1 or Value2.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what RDMBS you're using, but if it's postgres, the `GREATEST` func can help here:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO ORDER BY GREATEST(Value1, Value2) desc;
```

As it sounds, the `GREATEST` func will return the higher value from the 2 columns for each row.

(other RDBMS's might also support `GREATEST` you'll have to check with what you're using)

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL. This function seems to return 'order by Value2 desc, Value1 desc'. A step in the right direction but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @sullysunday are you sure based on the output that that's what's happening? Also did you make sure to enclose both `Value1` and `Value2` in the parentheses? According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm) and [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php): `GREATEST` returns the largest value in a list of values, just as postgres's version does. What's the datatype of `Value1` and `Value2`? Are you running it on your example data, or does what you tried this on contain nulls (as nulls have different behaviors in comparison ops)?

Comment: The order by greatest will return the highest value between value1 and value2, and that's what you asked, isn't it? Value2 desc, value1 desc will return something else.

Comment: Everything is enclosed in the parens, the datatypes are integers. I am running it on actual data, not example data but there are no nulls, just values greater than and including 0. It returns the rows in order (C,D,A,B)

Answer (score 0):

This is on MySQL:

`select * from tablename order by 
case when value1<value2 then value2 else value1 end desc;`

order changes with asc or desc